# getAttribute from DOM object not returning attributes

Tags: php, xml, getattribute

I am writing a program which sources economic and social statistics from multiple external sources and ingests them in a database (for data analyis).  Some of the data comes in XML format and to parse it I need to identify elements / tags as well as attributes in the XML file.  To identify attributes I have tried using getAttribute.

The problem:  Whilst getElementsByTagName works, getAttribute doesn't. Trying to retrieve the value of attribute 'Index' from a cell element returns "" even though attribute 'Index' does exists in a number of the cell elements.  There is no error, just no value returned.

I have spent a number of days reading PHP manuals and researching the Internet to try to find a solution but with no success. 
Echoing or var_dump on the return value of getAttribute shows it always return "".
Instead of putting the whole source code I have reproduced a simpler version of reading the XML file below which will have the same problem of not being able to return Attributes (in this case the 'Index' attribute).

```
<?php

// Creates new DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
// Loads XML file into DOMDocument
$dom->load('FRED_formatted_list.xml');

// Stores all the instances of the Row tag into $rows
$rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName('Row');

// Iterates through all the instances of the Row tag
foreach($rows as $row) {

// Stores all the instances of the Cell tag into $cells
$cells = $row->getElementsByTagName('Cell');

// Iterates through all the instances of the Cell tag
foreach($cells as $cell) {

    // Checks if the Index attribute exists in the cell tag
    if($cell->hasAttribute('Index')) {
        // Stores the value of any instances of the Index attribute
        $attr = $cell->getAttribute('Index');
        // Prints the value of any instances of the Index attribute to screen
        echo "Value of index attribute: " . $attr . "<br>";

    }
    // Check that the cell tags have been properly identified in the DOM Object
    echo $cell->nodeValue . "<br>";
    // Double checks whether any index values are even found and stored in $attr
    var_dump($attr) . "<br>";
}
}
?>
```

Here is a sample of the XML file which shows that the attribute 'Index' does exists even though not returned by getAttributes:

```
<Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">AAA</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="3"><Data ss:Type="String">Board of Governors of the Federal Reserve System (US)</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">H.15 Selected Interest Rates</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Percent</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Not Seasonally Adjusted</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">The Federal Reserve Board has discontinued this series as of October 11, 2016. More information, including possible alternative series, can be found at http://www.federalreserve.gov/feeds/h15.html. </Data></Cell>
</Row>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  I will summarise the solution and re-post to help others.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at `DOMXpath::evaluate()`, too. Using Xpath makes it a lot easier to read data from a DOM document.

Answer (score 0):

Define namespace in xml:

```
<Row xmlns:ss="something">
  <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">AAA</Data></Cell>
  <Cell ss:Index="3"><Data ss:Type="String">Board of Governors of the Federal Reserve System (US)</Data></Cell>
  <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">H.15 Selected Interest Rates</Data></Cell>
  <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Percent</Data></Cell>
  <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Not Seasonally Adjusted</Data></Cell>
  <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">The Federal Reserve Board has discontinued this series as of October 11, 2016. More information, including possible alternative series, can be found at http://www.federalreserve.gov/feeds/h15.html. </Data></Cell>
</Row>
```

Try the following code to get value of attribute with namespace:

```
<?php

  // Creates new DOMDocument
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  // Loads XML file into DOMDocument
  $dom->load('FRED_formatted_list.xml');

  // Stores all the instances of the Row tag into $rows
  $rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName('Row');
  $attr ='';
  // Iterates through all the instances of the Row tag
  foreach($rows as $row) {

     // Stores all the instances of the Cell tag into $cells
     $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName('Cell');

    // Iterates through all the instances of the Cell tag
    foreach($cells as $cell) {
        // Checks if the Index attribute exists in the cell tag
       if($cell->attributes->getNamedItem('Index')) {
           // Stores the value of any instances of the Index attribute
           $attr = $cell->attributes->getNamedItem('Index')->nodeValue;
           // Prints the value of any instances of the Index attribute to screen
            echo "Value of index attribute: " . $attr . "<br>";

        }
     // Check that the cell tags have been properly identified in the DOM Object
     echo $cell->nodeValue . "<br>";
     // Double checks whether any index values are even found and stored in $attr
     var_dump($attr) . "<br>";


   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake out.   I must have been a bit sloppy when rewriting this simplified example from the source code (which has $cell correctly stated).  The problem persist after the correction though.  There is still no return in using getAttribute

Comment: I have edit the code above with the correction to avoid distraction at future reviews

Comment: As an update, I tried a var_dump on each $cell and it seems to say that attributes are omitted when loading the XML into the DOM object.  This is from the var_dump:  
public 'attributes' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
If that is the case then the question is why are the Attributes stripped out when loading the XML file into a DOM object?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope this will help you. @ChrisE

Answer (score 0):

After additional research I found someone else who encountered this problem and managed to solve it.  The attribute 'Index' in the XML cell tag/element is pre-fixed with 'ss:' (as per XML file extract above `<Cell ss:Index="3"><Data ss:Type="String">`).  For getAttribute to work the 'ss:' needs to be included e.g. the correct code would be `getAttribute('ss:Index')` instead of 
`getAttribute('Index')`
I don't fully understand how the `getAttribute` identifies an attribute but it may be that is searches for a string of consecutive characters with a space before and therefore 'ss:' needs to be included.